# Problem with C++ Constructor. What exactly is getting initialized here?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, public

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class Vehicle
{
private:
int speed;

public:
Vehicle(int x)
{
   speed=x;
   cout << "Vehicle's parametrized constructor called" << endl;
}
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{ 
   public:
   Car() : Vehicle(5)
   {
        cout << "Car's constructor called" << endl;
   }
};

int main()
{
    Car a;
}
```

Output-
Vehicle's parametrized constructor called
Car's constructor called

Since the access specifier is public, speed is not inherited. What does 5 get assigned to as there is no speed member in Car?

Comment: *"Since the access specifier is public, speed is not inherited"*... what? I suggest you read a bit more about inheritance, derived classes contain *all members* of their base classes.

Comment: private attributes are never inherited. To my knowledge

Comment: They most certainly are inherited. You cannot access them from derived classes though.

Comment: `private` vs `protected` specifies *access* to the members, but does not prohibit them from existing

Comment: @jamesgem private members are inherited, you just aren't allowed to reference them unless you are a friend of the class where they were declared.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since the access specifier is public, speed is not inherited.

This is a misunderstanding. A derived class does inherit all members from the base class. What access specifier control is only whether the inherited class can access the members. The `Car` cannot directly access `speed` but the member is there.

Remember that public inheritance models a "is-a" relationship. A `Car` is a `Vehicle`. If `Car` didn't have the `speed` member it would not be a `Vehicle`.

Comment: Got it . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use a display function to test that for yourself.

Add this function to your class `Vehicle` under public access specifier:

```cpp
void display() { std::cout<<speed; }
```

Now from an object of derived class `Car`, call this function in `main()`:

```cpp
Car a; a.display();
```

It will output `5`, which is the value of the variable `speed` you have initialzed in derived class `Car`, from base class `Vehicle`.

> Since the access specifier is public, speed is not inherited.

Irrespective of access specifiers imposed, all variables are inherited. The difference is that they are not accessible directly. For `private` members like `speed`, you'll need to access them via a public member function, just like I did above.

> What does 5 get assigned to as there is no speed member in Car?

It gets assigned to the derived variable `speed` in objects of `Car`.

Answer (score 2):

Class Car is derived from Vehicle. when you create an object of class Car, it contains the memory for Vehicle also. it means object of class Car has Vehicle as a member.
Hope [this link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/) will give a good understanding.

when you are creating an object of Car, it will call constructor of class Car which internally call constructor of class Vehicle before executing the body of Car constructor.

```
 Car() : Vehicle(5)
```

This is a way of initializing the members of Vehicle class.
There is a concept of [Initializer List in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) and you can [read here](https://www.studytonight.com/cpp/initializer-list-in-cpp.php) when it is better to use.

Value 5 is passed to Vehicle's constructor and eventually stored in class member **speed**  .In your code if you print **speed**, you will see, whatever value you are passing is getting stored there.